# Unable to attach tensorboard callback in tensorflow keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am training a logistic regression based model and also trying to view the computational graph in tensorboard.  However, when I run the code, I get the error mentioned below.

Without attaching the callback, my model.fit() runs perfectly. Also as it was suggested, I have added `update_freq = 1000`

```
logdir = os.path.join("logs", datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S"))
tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(logdir, histogram_freq=1, update_freq=1000)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)])

model.compile(optimizer='sgd',
loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(np.matrix(train_X), np.matrix(train_y).T, epochs=10, callbacks=[tensorboard_callback])
```

However, i am getting this error:

```
    AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-73-90c175274a55> in <module>()
      8 metrics=['accuracy'])
      9 
---> 10 model.fit(np.matrix(train_X), np.matrix(train_y).T, epochs=20, callbacks=[tensorboard_callback])

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
    878     """Returns the loss value & metrics values for the model in test mode.
    879 
--> 880     Computation is done in batches.
    881 
    882     Arguments:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_arrays.py in model_iteration(model, inputs, targets, sample_weights, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, val_inputs, val_targets, val_sample_weights, shuffle, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, mode, validation_in_fit, **kwargs)
    250         # Loop over dataset for the specified number of steps.
    251         target_steps = steps_per_epoch
--> 252 
    253       step = 0
    254       while step < target_steps:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/callbacks.py in on_epoch_begin(self, epoch, logs, mode)
    235           'to the batch update (%f). Check your callbacks.', hook_name,
    236           delta_t_median)
--> 237 
    238   def _call_begin_hook(self, mode):
    239     """Helper function for on_{train|test|predict}_begin methods."""

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/callbacks.py in on_epoch_begin(self, epoch, logs)
   1139         samples. Note that writing too frequently to TensorBoard can slow down
   1140         your training.
-> 1141       profile_batch: Profile the batch to sample compute characteristics. By
   1142         default, it will profile the second batch. Set profile_batch=0 to
   1143         disable profiling. Must run in TensorFlow eager mode.

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fetches'
```

Need help!

Comment: I think the problem is within the training.. try removing the `callback` and run the code and tell me what happens

Comment: As i have mentioned, It runs perfectly without the callback

Comment: it worked when i removed `histogram_freq` arg

Comment: Could you write that as the answer??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation states:

> histogram_freq: frequency (in epochs) at which to compute activation
>   and weight histograms for the layers of the model. If set to 0,
>   histograms won't be computed. Validation data (or split) must be
>   specified for histogram visualizations.

setting histogram_freq = 1 was making it compute histograms at every epoch. Hence the error. 
Setting it to 0 won't compute histograms and setting it to lets say 5 will compute histograms at every 5th epoch.

Answer (score 0):

You must set `validation_data` in `fit` to use `histogram_freq`.

Just pass in some data in the format of (x, y), or a dataset/dataset-iterator.

This is nice, because it allows you to use a different dataset than your training in tensor-board.

```
model = create_model()
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

log_dir="logs/fit/" +
datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S") tensorboard_callback
= tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=log_dir, histogram_freq=1)

model.fit(x=x_train, # works with generator/iterator datasets, too.
          y=y_train, 
          epochs=5, 
--------> validation_data=(x_test, y_test), # or pass in your dataset iterator/generator
          callbacks=[tensorboard_callback])
```

example from TF Keras using callback documentation:
https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/r2/get_started#using_tensorboard_with_keras_modelfit

Then, just fire up Tensorboard:

```
tensorboard --logdir=path/to/logs/
```